# Harmonizing the bebop major (diminished sixth) scale - Barry Harris

Tags: harmony, jazz

@JohnBelzaguy shared this link with me https://cochranemusic.com/barry-harris-6th-dim-scale-diminished.

It's about Barry Harris and the "diminished sixth" - Bebop major - scale.

But I'm having trouble understanding the basic harmonization Harris is teaching in the video, because the students are having trouble playing it.

This YouTube video is linked right at the time of the scale harmonization:

Are my two harmonizations below right? Harris starts with a `Cmaj7` and then seems to just go up the scale in parallel movement...

[image]

[image]

I'm wondering if a few of my chord symbols are correct? `dimΔ7`, `mΔ7`, `Δ7♭5` some of those are on multiple roots.

Comment: There are a few better videos of this on YouTube, here’s one: https://youtu.be/_n0vuuKdUyM This and a few others have the benefit of Barry not trying to correct people that are scuffling to play it for the first time, phew!

Comment: In the minor version, the fourth chord you call "F dim maj7" ... but it has an Eb? That's not a chord symbol I've ever used, but if it should follow the same logic as your other "dim maj7" chords, then it should have an E natural, right? So that symbol is probably wrong. To me it's more like a rootless G7#5b9

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica you’re right, it should just be a Fm7b5. It’’s the only chord on beats 2 or 4 that’s different from major to minor btw. Actually the reason I’m commenting is more to say that almost all the chords on beats 2 and 4 sound like rootless dominants to me, the G7#5b9 could also be a rootless Db9. Also the G#dimΔ7 sounds like an E7#9 or a Bb13 b9. Several of the chords on beats 2 and 4 sound like rootless dominants to my ear since I’m used to playing them in general.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica, I correct the chart for the Fm7b5, thanks for spotting that.

Comment: I see the point about Fm7♭5 and G♯dimΔ7 as dominants or their tritone substitutions, that makes sense as they would resolve to the tonic and it's relative minor. I suppose what I labelled AdimΔ7 and E♭Δ7♭5? would be dominants to Bb moving out of key or tritone subs. to E minor. Does that make sense? My initial question wasn't about _application_ of these odd chords - I just wanted to know if I understood the video lesson - but understanding their use if of course the ultimate goal.

Comment: If I understand the application of these chord correctly, it seems those on basses C, D, G, B have their typical roles of tonic, subdominant, dominant, and the other chords on basses E, F, A can be viewed as various rootless dominants to the tonic, submediant, or mediant, except Em7sus4 and AmΔ7 being mediant and submediant. Is this the basic jist?

Comment: What chord is "Cmaj7" in the sixth diminished scale really? If the basic idea is that in this 8-note scale, building "stacks of thirds" produces only two different chords or functions, tonic and dominant ... then in that sense, a C - E - G - B chord is not a stack of thirds in the scale, because the last interval G - B is actually a _fourth_. So if we use C - E - G - B that's called "Cmaj7", and move that along the scale, do we now have more than two functions?

Answer (score 8):

### The basic concept

Speaking broadly, **the point of the bebop scale approach to block-chord harmony is that you don't have to think of a different chord for each melody note.** For a major chord, if the melody note is the 1, 3, 5, or 6, you play a major 6 shape (`C6`), and if the melody is the 2, 4, ♭6, or 7, you play a diminished 7 shape (`Bdim7`).

The result looks like this. I have put the voicings in close position, assuming you know how to drop the second voice to make it match yours:
[image]

**Note that in Barry Harris's conception a "major" chord is a major 6, and the 7th scale degree or leading tone is a non–chord tone.** If your example had a prominent B on a downbeat, then I would harmonize using a `Cmaj7` shape or something similar. But this would be somewhat beside the point, because the context for this discussion is, **how do we harmonize a melody built from the bebop scale?** The principle of bebop scales is that only chord tones appear on downbeats, so if a melody is written purely using the C major bebop scale, you will *never* have B (or D, F, or A♭) on a downbeat.

That is to say that **the chord voicings Harris is teaching in this video aren't meant to be a comprehensive formula for harmonizing any melody.** Any real melody will have some parts that can be interpreted as coming from the bebop scale and others that can't; these voicings apply only to the former.

Also note that for other qualities of chord, there are other bebop scales. The dominant bebop scale is the most important one after the major bebop scale here. These scales also yield two-chord alternating harmonic patterns that can be used to harmonize melodies that use the scale.

I've discussed these considerations on this site before [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/99478/how-to-apply-barry-harris-6th-diminished-voicings-and-maintain-chord-functions/99479#99479), but let me excerpt a relevant part:

> A different set of voicings, derived from the appropriate bebop scale, is used for each chord. Over the I chord, the voicings come from the **major bebop scale** and alternate between the major I6 and vii°7 chords. This is because the stable scale degrees (1, 3, 5, and 6) tend to sit on the downbeats, so we'll hear the sound of the I chord on the downbeats and a passing chord, vii°7, on the upbeats. This principle of alternating between the main chord and passing chords is central to Barry Harris's harmonic concept, and also used widely in big band arranging.
>
> Over ii and V, we generally use the **mixolydian bebop scale.** In C, that's `G A B C D E F F#`, adding a major 7. The two chord shapes outlined are G7 and  F♯ø7, and a well-constructed melody usually again has G, B, D, and F on downbeats, so the F♯ø7 acts as a passing chord. (Occasionally, one note can be swapped around in order to create smooth voice leading; changing the E here to a E♭ to form F♯°7 is a natural choice.)

There is also a "melodic minor" bebop scale; here I have written out the voicings for a `Cm6` to parallel your second line. It's nearly the same, just changing E to E♭:

[image]

As for practicing these voicings, I would recommend doing as you have done, writing out the voicings in both close and drop-2 (and maybe drop-2-4 as well) forms, and practicing walking up and down the major scale in various keys. The goal is to get to a point where just looking at the keyboard, you can "see" which notes belong to the "chord tones"/major 6 subset of the bebop scale and which ones belong to the "non–chord tones"/diminished 7 subset. Then the rest of the notes in the voicing just fall in place below the melody.

### What's happening in the video

**At the point in the video you have linked to, Harris is introducing a more advanced application** of the bebop scales that disregards the "alternating chords" principles outlined above. Your transcription is correct, but you should note that that set of voicings is just one of an arbitrary number that you could generate by picking *any* shape from within the bebop scale and moving each voice up and down in diatonic parallel. Rather than getting hung up on playing that exact line, developing the mental dexterity to walk through the bebop scale using any shape would be a better practice goal.

The editing of the video makes it easy to think that this follows directly from the "basic" bebop scale harmonic conception, when in fact there are multiple things going on: Harris is treating the bebop scale as a mode, and applying another harmonization technique, namely, the technique of moving a shape diatonically through a scale or mode, to it.

So (and this is just my opinion), **I wouldn't ascribe special significance to the chord voicings you have transcribed.** Rather, we have one concept (bebop scales) and another concept (parallel diatonic harmonization) and they are being used simultaneously.

When someone says "bebop scale harmonization," they are usually referring to the more narrow process outline above.

Comment: In the video they are starting from Cmaj7, aren't they?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean re. repeating the B. If you check OP's transcription it's clearly what Harris is expecting – e.g. he says "fourths. fourths!" when they get to the Em11 (or Em7sus4 as OP has it) on the way back down. I haven't been able to grab the audio to really convince myself the transcription's accurate but the circumstantial evidence is good --eta: I'm starting the video at 6.29 per the OP's link

Comment: As far as I could tell OP was asking about what happens in that bit of the video ;)

Comment: This is a long answer to a question I didn't ask. I already know about the block chord method. The video presents something different.

Comment: See my last four paragraphs.

Comment: How does that answer whether my notation is what Harris wants the students to play in the part of the video I linked? The problem is the students keep making mistakes. I _think_ I know what Harris wants played, but I'm looking for confirmation of only that.

Comment: "Your transcription is correct."

Comment: This was really helpful! I couldn't figure out what to do on the 7th chord in lieu of the 7 being included in the maj6 inverions, but the fact that he treats it like a passing chord (and therefore a diminished chord being appropriate) unlocked the concept. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

People who are into the "Barry Harris" approach seem to be characteristically bad at explaining the point, the purpose, the context, or the intended use of the concept, or maybe perhaps people trying to 'get to grips' with it are expecting a much more holistic and enlightening result than it is reasonable to expect. The point as far as I see it is that when you harmonise, say, the C major scale the traditional way (that is, taking Cmaj7 and repeatedly moving every voice up to the next tone in the C major scale), you get chords with strong harmonic pulls *away* from C major. Whereas if you add in your favourite extra note, all the chords in the resulting harmonised scale generally feel more or less as if they belong in, or over, C major. You have the details exactly right, but it's really not significant what the chord names of the voicings generated are; the idea is "this is all C major stuff"

Comment: I think you should explain "the traditional way". Meaning, stacks of thirds, i.e. every second note? All chords that are possible with the major scale are possible with the sixth diminished scale as well, so the point must be what happens when you take every Nth note of the scale.

Comment: Yes, as in applying the same principal but only using the notes we have at our disposal in the C major scale

Comment: What you call taking Cmaj7 is usually called stacks of thirds, meaning to take every 2nd note of the scale. It extends to Cmaj9, and in theory to Cmaj11, Cmaj13. That's how chords and harmony are built in traditional Western music. If you use other scales, you get different phenomena when taking every other note.

Comment: Ok I think I see the point you're getting at; I'd say this is focussing more on the meaning of "harmonise the C major scale the traditional way" than I really intended – I just meant "do the thing that's being done here, with the C major scale".

Comment: I meant to say that your answer seems to assume that everyone knows what "the traditional way" is without explaining, or that a maj7 chord is a traditional stereotypical harmonization. In what genres and traditions is this? IMO the answer would benefit from explaining these a little bit.

Comment: (not least as trying to view Barry Harris stuff in terms of universal harmonic organisational principles is exactly what I think goes wrong with attempts to understand/apply it! It's "here's a way to generate some cool stuff that sounds good" rather than "this unlocks a new theoretical realm of jazz harmony")

Comment: My concern was only whether my notation was what Harris presented in the video. I only added chord symbols treating the basses and roots. But I think I understand from the other comments many of these chords should be considered rootless voicings of various dominant and tritone substitutes.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis Yes, but (also seeing your subsequent comments) I thought I should warn against – or, to put it a little milder, point away from – over-interpretation of the resulting voicings. For my money, even to say they should be considered this, or considered that, is overegging it – they're voicings you can move up and down through over C major and be reasonably confident it will sound "fine", or "hip". It's just like if you're on C major, and you go Dm7-Ebm7-Em7 – it sounds like you're comping C major. But you don't need to think about the harmonic possibilities of those chords –

Comment: you just run a m7 up from the ii to the iii and you know pretty well in advance what it'll sound like

Comment: Ah, I think I see your point. Especially if the parallel motion is quick you don't hear bona fide chords, it's like passing motion. I did compare this scale harmonization with the block chord (C6 positions with dim7 passing) and after alternating both several times, at a fairly quick pace, it starts to sound the same. At a lower tempo, if wanting to treat these odd voicings like dimΔ7 as bona fide chords, resolving them as some kind of rootless dominant seems to work nicely.

Comment: @JudyN. Do you mean to say that this Barry Harris scale is sort of like just a way to generate chords that create a sense of motion without actually moving anywhere? Meaning that you layer this "system" over, say, C major,  you kind of stay at C major whatever you do ... but if the "real" chord degree changes to, say, F major, then you should layer a slightly different sixth diminished scale on top of that F major? Can you give an example of what should be played if the "real" chord is F?

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Well... I can only say how I see it, and, like I say, there's a lot of BH 'discussion' that remains totally opaque to me so maybe others have something else going on. But yes, that gets close to how I see it – however I would say, the way you've phrased it puts me in mind of "what scale should I play over this chord" kind of questions. Just as picking a set of notes to play over, say, Am, depends on *personal taste and *where you are in the tune, and just as you might play A dorian, A aeolian, harmonic minor, melodic, bop minor, whole tone, depending on what the tune's

Comment: doing and what side of bed you got out of in the morning, the idea of these scales of chords is to give you ammunition in your arsenal that you have at your disposal, and can call upon at will, as something to play.